# Spring's AuthenticationManager not being properly injected

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-security

I'm building a REST endpoint to authenticate (login) users. I'm using a custom authentication provider for this.

My context.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foobar" />

    <bean id="authDao" class="com.foobar.security.ldap.AuthProviderImpl">
    </bean>
    <bean id="myAuthProvider" class="com.foobar.security.MyAuthProvider">
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http
        realm="Protected API"
        use-expressions="true"
        auto-config="false"
        create-session="stateless"
        entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />

        <security:intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/rest/autenticacion/login" access="permitAll" />

    </security:http>

    <bean id="unauthorizedEntryPoint" class="com.foobar.security.UnauthorizedEntryPoint" />

    <bean id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" class="com.foobar.security.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="authDao" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The definition of my custom auth provider (myAuthProvider) is as follows

```
package com.foobar.security;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;

@Component
public class MyAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final ResourceBundle properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("security");

    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService authDao;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = (String)authentication.getCredentials();

        if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.authDao.loadUserByUsername(username);
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad username or password");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

My AuthProviderImpl class is as follows

```
package com.foobar.security.ldap;

import com.foobar.security.AuthProvider;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AuthProviderImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (username.equals("admin")) {
            return new UserDetailsImpl("admin", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ADMIN" }));
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
    }

}
```

My UserDetailsImpl class is as follows

```
package com.foobar.security.ldap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private final String username;
    private final Date accountExpirationDate;
    private final Boolean locked;
    private final Date credentialsExpirationDate;
    private final Boolean enabled;
    private final List<String> roles;

    public UserDetailsImpl(String username, Date accountExpirationDate, Boolean locked, Date credentialsExpirationDate, Boolean enabled, List<String> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.accountExpirationDate = accountExpirationDate;
        this.locked = locked;
        this.credentialsExpirationDate = credentialsExpirationDate;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public UserDetailsImpl(String username, List<String> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.accountExpirationDate = null;
        this.locked = false;
        this.credentialsExpirationDate = null;
        this.enabled = true;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> rolList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(this.roles.size());

        for (String role : this.roles) {
            rolList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }

        return rolList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return this.accountExpirationDate != null && this.accountExpirationDate.after(new Date());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !this.locked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return this.credentialsExpirationDate != null && this.credentialsExpirationDate.after(new Date());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

}
```

And finally my REST endpoint

```
package com.foobar.rest;

import com.foobar.rest.dto.AutenticacionDTO;
import com.foobar.security.AuthProvider;
import com.foobar.security.TokenUtils;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/autenticacion")
public class AutenticacionEndpoint {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AutenticacionEndpoint.class);

    @Inject
    private AuthProvider authDao;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @POST
    @Path("login")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response autenticar(AutenticacionDTO datos) {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(datos.getUsuario(), datos.getClave());
        AutenticacionDTO response;
        UserDetails userDetails = null;

        try {
            userDetails = this.authDao.loadUserByUsername(datos.getUsuario());
            /// THIS PART FAILS SINCE this.authenticationManager equals NULL - NullPointerException
            Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            Map<String, Boolean> roles = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(authentication.getAuthorities().size());

            for (GrantedAuthority auth : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
                roles.put(auth.getAuthority(), Boolean.TRUE);
            }

            response = new AutenticacionDTO(userDetails.getUsername(), Boolean.TRUE, null, null, TokenUtils.createToken(userDetails), !userDetails.isAccountNonExpired(), !userDetails.isCredentialsNonExpired());

            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(response).build();
        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            if (userDetails != null) {
                response = new AutenticacionDTO(datos.getUsuario(), "Fallo en autenticacion", !userDetails.isAccountNonExpired(), !userDetails.isCredentialsNonExpired());
            } else {
                response = new AutenticacionDTO(datos.getUsuario(), false, "Usuario o contraseña inválidos");
            }

            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(response).build();
        }

    }
}
```

Why isn't `authenticationManager` being injected at the endpoint? In that last class I also had "authDao" as `@Autowired` but it didn't get injected either until I replaced it by `@Inject` annotation. But I can't use `@Inject` with `authenticationManager` since it does not recognizes it as an bean.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your REST endpoint is not being created by Spring but by your JAX-WS container, and Spring never sees it. You'll need to make that instance visible to Spring or acquire the authentication manager in a different way.

Comment: @chrylis I forgot to say it's using RESTEasy since it's deployed on JBoss AS7. How do I make it visible to Spring? Wasn't the `@Component` directive required? Should I declare it as a bean?

Comment: No, that will just create a separate instance. Look at the `@Configurable` option in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but Spring beans weren't being injected, as my custom classes were. I solved this by doing a "dirty" thing. In the `autenticar` method of my REST endpoint, I added the following code:

```
@Path("login")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response autenticar(AutenticacionDTO datos, @Context ServletContext servletContext) {
    logger.trace("AutenticacionEndpoint - autenticar");

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(datos.getUsuario(), datos.getClave());
    AutenticacionDTO response;
    UserDetails userDetails = null;

    try {
        userDetails = this.authDao.loadUserByUsername(datos.getUsuario());
        if (this.authenticationManager == null) {
            ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
            this.authenticationManager = ctx.getBean("authenticationManager", AuthenticationManager.class);
        }
...
```

I hope this helps someone, or maybe someone has a better option.